# Optimal control for single qubit gate

Tags: quantum-computer, bloch-sphere

Suppose we want to implement a single qubit gate $U$ and are only able to apply rotations around axes in the $xy$ plane of the Bloch Sphere, i.e. we can only apply Hamiltonians of the form
$$H(t) = \frac{\Omega(t)}{2}\left(\cos(\phi(t))\sigma_x+\sin(\phi(t))\sigma_y\right).$$

We want to achieve $U$ through a path that minimizes
$$\int_0^T \Omega(t)^2 dt.$$

How do we find this path? If it simplifies the problem we can restrict ourselves to $U$ being rotations around the $z$ axis.

In principle we could of course parametrize the path $\Omega(t)$ as, say, a piecewise constant function and then let an optimizer find the best path, but I'm rather looking for something like the Euler-Lagrange equations that would allow us to find the solution analytically. Any idea where to start is appreciated.

Comment: you probably already know this, but there's plenty of methods used for quantum optimal control of quantum gates. See e.g. https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11128-019-2190-0